# MySQL Workbench formatter CTRL+B erases my comments

Tags: mysql, comments, mysql-workbench, formatter

When I press CTRL+B in order to beautifully format my SQL code in MySQL Workbench 6.3.10, all my explanation comments are erased from the query. SQL query is code, so we should be able to add a comment after each line, shouldn't we?

I could not find formatter options menu.

Comment: It is still a bug and not fixed in latest version. Take a look : https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65523

Comment: Indeed it wasn't fix since it was reported in 2012! Thank you. Wait and see...

Comment: An explanation: this isn't really a bug but a feature (TM). The beautifier uses the bult-in parser (the old one, there are 2 in WB) and parsers usually ignore whitespaces (including comments). So, when the parser tree reaches the formatter the comments are already gone and hence cannot be re-inserted in the reformatted code. This part is planned to be rewritten using only the newer lexer.

Comment: I wish Beautify would not remove my comments. But those neglected bug reports are not encouraging.